# Организовать перегруз с помощью обращений к полям

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть вот такой код

```
Set Set::operator * (const Set &b)
{  
size = a.size + b.size; // понятное дело что здесь будет ругаться компилятор, он вообще будет ругаться на все где есть а
array = new unsigned int[size]; 
unsigned int i, j, n = 0; 

for ( i = 0; i < a.size; i++) 
    for ( j = 0; j < b.size; j++) 
    { 
        if(a.array[i] == b.array[j]) 
        {
            array[n++] = a.array[i]; 
            continue;
        } 
    } 
    size = n;
}
```

Мне бы хотелось сделать просто перегруз через добавления обращения к полям. Ну там заместо size написать NewSet.size а как сделать не знаю. Помогите кодом или объяснением чтобы не переписывать весь код.

```
а вот код полностью 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Set 
{ 
private: 
unsigned int size;  // ðàçìåð ìàññèâà
unsigned int* array;  // óêàçàòåëü ìàññèâà
public: 
Set() { size=0; array = new unsigned int[size]; } // êîíñòðóêòîð 

Set(int s) {  size = s; array = new unsigned int[size]; // êîíñòðóêòîð ñ 
àðãóìåíòàìè
              for ( unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) 
                  array[i] = 0;  }

Set(const Set &ob) // êîíñòðóêòîð êîïèè
{   size = ob.size;  
    array = new unsigned  int[size]; 
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
          array[i] = ob.array[i]; } 

~Set() { delete [] array; }  // äåñòðóêòîð
void Enter(); // ââîä
void Show(); // âûâîä
void Union(Set, Set); // îáúåäèíåíèå 
void intersection(Set, Set); // ïåðåñå÷åíèå
void operator = (Set); // ïåðåãðóçêè 
int operator [] (int i); 
void Raznost(Set, Set); //ðàçíîñòü
}; 
void Set::Enter() 
{ 
std::cout << "Ââåäèòå ðàçìåð ìíîæåñòâà " << std::endl; 
std::cin >> size;  
array = new unsigned int[size];
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{ 
    std::cout << "Ââåäèòå ýëåìåíò " << i + 1 << ")   "; 
    std::cin >> array[i]; 
} 
}  
void Set::Show() 
{ 
std::cout << "Ìíîæåñòâî " << std::endl; 
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    std::cout << array[i] << " "; 
std::cout << std::endl;
}  
void Set::Union(Set a, Set b) 
{ 
this->size = a.size + b.size;  
this->array = new unsigned int[size];
unsigned i, j, count = 0; 
unsigned int n = a.size;
for ( i = 0; i < a.size; i++) 
    array[i] = a.array[i]; 

for ( i = 0; i < b.size; i++) 
{ 
    for ( j = 0; j < a.size; j++) 
        if(b.array[i] == a.array[j]) 
            continue; 
        else 
            count++; 
    if(count == a.size) 
        array[n++] = b.array[i];  
    count = 0;
} 
size = n;
}  
void Set::intersection(Set a, Set b) 
{  
size = a.size + b.size; 
array = new unsigned int[size]; 
unsigned int i, j, n = 0; 

for ( i = 0; i < a.size; i++) 
    for ( j = 0; j < b.size; j++) 
    { 
        if(a.array[i] == b.array[j]) 
        {
            array[n++] = a.array[i]; 
            continue;
        } 
    } 
    size = n;
 } 
 void Set::Raznost(Set a, Set b)
{
array = new unsigned int[size]; 
unsigned int i, n = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
 { int j = 0;
   while (j < b.size && b[j] != a[i]) j++;
   if (j == b.size) cout << a[i] << "\t";
 }  
 cout << "\n" << endl;
 } 
void Set::operator = (Set a) 
{ 
unsigned int i;
delete[] this->array; 
this->size = a.size; 
this->array = new unsigned int[size]; 
for ( i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    array[i] = a.array[i];
} 
int Set::operator[](int i) 
{ 
return array[i];
} 
int main() 
{  
setlocale(0, "rus");  
Set a; 
std::cout << "Ââîä è âûâîä 1 ìíîæåñòâà " << std::endl;
a.Enter(); 
a.Show(); 
Set b = a;
std::cout << "èíèöèàëèçàöèÿ ìíîæåñòâà 2 ñ ïîìîùüþ êîíñòðóêòîðà êîïèè "<< 
std::endl; 
b.Show();
std::cout << "Ââîä ìíîæåñòâà 2 " << std::endl;
b.Enter(); 
Set c;  
std::cout << "Îáúåäèíåíèå ìíîæåñòâ " << std::endl;
c.Union(a, b);  
c.Show(); 
std::cout << "Ïåðåñå÷åíèå " << std::endl;
c.intersection(a, b);  
c.Show();
std::cout << "Ðàçíîñòü a/b " << std::endl;
c.Raznost(a,b);
 std::cout << "Ðàçíîñòü b/a " << std::endl;
c.Raznost(b,a); 
}
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь в том, что вы хотите, то либо вам нужно сделать свободный оператор

`Set operator * (const Set &a, const Set &b)`

то ли просто использовать вместо `a.` - `this->` (или не использовать `a.` вовсе, где это не вызовет неоднозначности).

Comment: Свободный оператор не получается так как оператор должен быть бинарный , а на this компилятор ругается

Comment: Какой, по-вашему, этот свободный оператор - `Set operator * (const Set &a, const Set &b)` - унарный или тернарный?... :)

Comment: Ну это понятно что он тернарный.А в таком случае реализовывать то его как? он же тогда мне 3 объекта сложит, а не два?

Comment: Вот код полностью

Comment: Нет смайлика, чтоб нарисовать челюсть на полу. Вы что, издеваетесь? Понятно, что он **бинарный**! И "Код полностью" - где?

Comment: Код наверху выложил

Comment: А тернарный я думаю потому что левый операнд же как будто автоматически в с++ есть. Вот и получается что один в уме и +два

Comment: Я же написал - **свободный**!!!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде вносим объявление:

```
    void Raznost(Set, Set);

    friend Set operator*(const Set&a, const Set&b);

};
```

Потом - вне класса! - определение (код пишите сами, у меня просто сумма множеств):

```
Set operator*(const Set&a, const Set&b)
{
    Set s(a.size+b.size);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size; ++i)
        s.array[k++] = a.array[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size; ++i)
        s.array[k++] = b.array[i];
    return s;
}
```

Ну, а где-то в `main` - использование:

```
c = a*b;
```

Все компилируется...

Или объявление в классе:

```
Set operator*(const Set&b);
```

Реализация:

```
Set Set::operator*(const Set&b)
{
    Set s(size+b.size);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        s.array[k++] = array[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size; ++i)
        s.array[k++] = b.array[i];
    return s;
}
```

Использование - такое же...

Comment: Так то да работает не спорю, а через указатель this  как делать?

Comment: Дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде! :) См. ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое..Ночевку сам буду организовывать))))

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - принимайте как принятый.

Comment: А почему в первом случае восклицательным знаком выделено "вне класса"? В чем проблема написать реализацию прямо в классе?

Comment: @AnT,  это для страховки наверное: чтобы  случайно не было написано  и обявление и определение

Comment: @AnT Чтобы автор вопроса не начал писать этот код как есть прямо в классе. Судя по уровню вопроса и тернарному оператору :) - это вполне могло бы быть. И пришлось бы пояснять опять...